# Auto increment of number input in Django Formset

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, python-3.6, formset

I am using django formset for adding multiple periodic inputs of price range

```
WarehousePriceSpacetSet = formset_factory(WarehouseSpacePricePerdayForm, extra=1)
```

this is my formset.

I need to append **from** input data with respect previous **to** data.
Here is the example[image]

Here the first row saving the prices of **1 to 10**
So next **Period from** field should auto fill **11**

I have tried with Jquery by appending value when **to** field change function.

```
for(i=0;i<=pallet_num;i++){
                        $(".pallet_to").change(function() {
                                $("#id_palletss-"+i+"-period_from_pallet").val($(this).val());
                                // $(".pallet_to").closest(".pallet_from").val($(this).val());
                        });
                 }
```

But the change function working only for first periods row. Because others are adding dynamically by clicking "Add more" in form-set.

Please help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need a little HTML to get a better view of how to fix this. Also what is it doing currently?

Comment: now its like normal input fields. but i need to make as auto complete with previous rows data